# Multiple auto_increment fields

Tags: mysql

I have a unique PK 'id' which is set to auto_increment.  I have a second field called 'label' which is an alphanumeric field (e.g. W1000) that is intended to increment on each insert using PHP logic.

The 'label' field may have one of many alpha prefixes, followed by the incrementing number.  Each prefix should increment independently.  For example, the table may have W1000 and F1123.  The next W would be W1001, and the next F would be F1124.

The current method (PHP select maximum label, insert maximum label + 1) creates a race condition, and occasionally I get a duplicate 'label'.  I need to resolve these duplicated 'labels' and ensure that this field is unique.  I am willing to split the prefix and the numeric into two fields if it helps.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Set the field to `UNIQUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to avoid generating duplicate label values is to use a MyISAM table to generate unique sequence numbers. MyISAM supports the behavior of AUTO_INCREMENT you need.

See the "MyISAM Notes" section in MySQL Reference [3.6.9. Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

For this approach, you would create a separate MyISAM table; the purpose of this table is to generate unique sequence numbers:e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
( prefix  VARHCAR(1) NOT NULL
, num     INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
, PRIMARY KEY (prefix, num)
) Engine=MyISAM
```

Assuming that the label prefix is one character, and the remainder is a numeric:

```
INSERT INTO foo (prefix, num)
SELECT SUBSTR(t.label,1,1) AS prefix
     , MAX(SUBSTR(t.label,2,8) AS num
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY SUBSTR(t.label,1,1)
```

Go get a new sequence number, insert a row to the new table, providing a value for prefix, and a NULL for the num column, and retrieve the value inserted for the num column:

```
INSERT INTO foo (prefix,num) VALUES ('W',NULL); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You can use that to construct the value to be used for the `label` column in your original table.

Note that it's only the MyISAM engine that has the behavior you want (separately incrementing AUTO_INCREMENT sequences for each prefix.)  Your original table can be whatever engine.

This approach avoids the race condition, but does introduce a concurrency bottleneck, due to the exclusive locks taken on the MyISAM table for the insert.

---

Another way to avoid the race condition is to obtain an exclusive lock on the table, then do a SELECT MAX(), then do an insert, then release the lock. But that approach introduces even more of a concurrency bottleneck, serializing access to a single resource.

---

If your question is about identifying the existing duplicate `label` values, then this query gets you rows that have a "duplicate" label.  (This is picking out just one row, for each duplicated label.)

```
SELECT t.label
     , MAX(t.id)
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.label
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

To update the labels to be unique, you would need to generate a new label for those rows.

Go get that done in a single SQL statement is a bit tricky. I tried to come up with a statement, but it was broken, and I don't have the time to fix it.